# com.bumptech.glide.Registry$NoModelLoaderAvailableException: Failed to find any ModelLoaders

Tags: android, android-glide

I am trying to load a custom model into Glide but getting this error:

> GlideExecutor: Request threw uncaught throwable
> com.bumptech.glide.Registry$NoModelLoaderAvailableException: Failed to
> find any ModelLoaders for model:
> com.company.project.glide.Movie@aac331a

**Glide Version**: 4.0.0

### My codes:

**Model**

```
public class Movie {
    private String name;
    private String artist;

    public Movie(String name, String artist) {
        this.name = name;
        this.artist = artist;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getArtist() {
        return artist;
    }
}
```

**Module**

```
@com.bumptech.glide.annotation.GlideModule
public class GlideModule  extends AppGlideModule {

    @Override
    public boolean isManifestParsingEnabled() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void applyOptions(Context context, GlideBuilder builder) {
        super.applyOptions(context, builder);
    }

    @Override
    public void registerComponents(Context context, Registry registry) {
        registry.append(Movie.class, InputStream.class, new MovieArtModel.Factory());
    }
}
```

**ModelLoader**

```
public class MovieArtModel implements ModelLoader<Movie, InputStream> {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public LoadData<InputStream> buildLoadData(Movie movie, int width, int height, Options options) {
        Timber.d("buildLoadData: ");
        return new LoadData<>(new ObjectKey(movie), new MovieArtLoader(movie, width, height));
    }


    @Override
    public boolean handles(Movie movie) {
        return false;
    }

    public static class Factory implements ModelLoaderFactory<Movie, InputStream> {

        @Override
        public ModelLoader<Movie, InputStream> build(MultiModelLoaderFactory multiFactory) {
            return new MovieArtModel();
        }

        @Override
        public void teardown() {
        }
    }


    static class MovieArtLoader implements DataFetcher<InputStream> {
        private Movie movie;
        private boolean isCancelled = false;
        private int widthSize;
        private int heightSize;

        MovieArtLoader(Movie movie, int widthSize, int heightSize) {
            Timber.d("MovieArtLoader: Initializing...width size = " + widthSize + " :: heightSize = " + heightSize);
            this.movie = movie;
            this.widthSize = widthSize;
            this.heightSize = heightSize;
        }

        @Override
        public void loadData(Priority priority, DataCallback<? super InputStream> callback) {
            Timber.d("loadData");

            //First check if request is not cancelled before starting request
            if(!isCancelled()) {
                InputStream inputStream = getMovieArtInputStream(movie);
                if (inputStream != null) {
                    callback.onDataReady(inputStream);
                } else {
                    callback.onLoadFailed(new IOException("Forced Glide network failure. Can't load Movie image"));
                }


            }
        }
            return null;
        }



        @Override public void cleanup() {
            Timber.d("cleanup: ");
        }


        @Override public void cancel() {
            Timber.d("cancel: ");
            isCancelled = true;
        }

        @Override
        public Class<InputStream> getDataClass() {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public DataSource getDataSource() {
            return null;
        }

        private boolean isCancelled() {
            return isCancelled;
        }
    }
```

Then I am loading it thus:

```
GlideApp.with(itemView.getContext())
                .asBitmap()
                .load(new Movie(book.getMovieName(), book.getArtist()))
                .placeholder(R.drawable.movie_default_small)
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.RESOURCE)
                .listener(this)
                .into(imageView);
```

Please where am I getting it wrong?

---

### EDIT

I applied the answer below but I began to get NPE. This is the stacktrace:

```
E/GlideExecutor: Request threw uncaught throwable
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.Object.hashCode()' on a null object reference
    at com.bumptech.glide.util.MultiClassKey.hashCode(MultiClassKey.java:66)
    at android.support.v4.util.SimpleArrayMap.indexOfKey(SimpleArrayMap.java:320)
    at android.support.v4.util.SimpleArrayMap.get(SimpleArrayMap.java:360)
    at com.bumptech.glide.provider.LoadPathCache.get(LoadPathCache.java:34)
    at com.bumptech.glide.Registry.getLoadPath(Registry.java:132)
    at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeHelper.getLoadPath(DecodeHelper.java:132)
    at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeHelper.hasLoadPath(DecodeHelper.java:128)
    at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.SourceGenerator.startNext(SourceGenerator.java:59)
    at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.runGenerators(DecodeJob.java:282)
    at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.runWrapped(DecodeJob.java:252)
    at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.run(DecodeJob.java:222)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
    at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.executor.GlideExecutor$DefaultThreadFactory$1.run(GlideExecutor.java:347)
```

Comment: register model in AndroidManifest.xml, or call Glide.with(context).using(new MovieArtLoader(), InputStream.class)....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**NoModelLoaderAvailableException** happened when no 
 {@linkcom.bumptech.glide.load.model.ModelLoader} is registered for a given
   model class, and that fixed with @talkLittle answer, and plus on that Movie should implement `equals()` and `hashCode()` to get caching to work correctly.

The new **NPE** happened because you accepted `@Nullable`  would try `@NonNull` annotation.

Comment: It is (still) not possible to understand this explanation, please update. "no {…} is registred for a given model class". What does this mean? How to register a loader?? What class? Nothing in the documentation sheds light. Please use teaspoon. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

```
@Override
public boolean handles(Movie movie) {
    return true;
}
```

You need to do this or else Glide will ignore your ModelLoader, thinking it does not handle the provided `Movie` model.

Comment: why not add some explanation?, so that it does not end up in [LQP Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/16914388)?

Comment: Thanks but I got an NPE. I have updated the question with the details though.

Comment: Sorry fo the late comment :), but you have got `NPE` because your `Movie` class doesn't override `equals` and `hashCode` methods, which is necessary for `Glide` to find your `Movie`.